# Issue with Hadoop and Google Cloud Storage Connector

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-storage, hadoop-streaming

I've deployed a hadoop cluster via Deployments interface in google console. (Hadoop 2.x)

My task was to filter data stored in one Google Storage (GS) bucket and put the results to another. So, this is a map only job with simple python script. Note that cluster and output bucket are in the same zone (EU).

Leveraging Google Cloud Storage Connector, I run the following streaming job:

```
 hadoop jar /home/hadoop/hadoop-install/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.4.1.jar \
-D mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress=true \
-D mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec \
-D mapreduce.job.reduces=0 \
-file file_1 \
-file mymapper.py \
-input gs://inputbucket/somedir/somedir2/*-us-* \
-output gs://outputbucket/somedir3/somedir2 \
-inputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat \
-mapper mymapper.py
```

What happens is all the mappers process data and store the results in temporary directory in GS, which looks like:

```
gs://outputbucket/somedir3/somedir2/_temporary/1/mapper-0000/part-0000.gz
```

After all mappers are finished, job progress hangs at 100% map, 0% reduce. Looking at output bucket with gsutil, I see that result files are being copied to the destination directory:

```
gs://outputbucket/somedir3/somedir2
```

This process takes a very long time and kills the whole benefit from using hadoop. 
My questions are:

1) Is it a known issue or I just done something wrong? I couldn't find any relevant info.

2) Am I correct saying that normally hdfs would move those files to destination dir, but GS can't perform move and thus the files are copied?

3) What can I do to avoid this pattern?

Comment: Are you using Hadoop 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: I'm using Hadoop 2.x

Comment: You are using deprecated properties.  Configure right properties from https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/DeprecatedProperties.html

Comment: Thanks, I changed the deprecated properties in my post to a proper property names. It didn't help though.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost certainly running into the ["Slow FileOutputCommitter" issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-4815) which affects Hadoop 2.0 through 2.6 inclusive and is fixed in 2.7.

If you're looking for a nice managed Hadoop option on Google Cloud Platform, you should consider [Google Cloud Dataproc](https://console.cloud.google.com/dataproc/clusters) (documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/create-cluster#using_the_cloud_dataproc_ui)), where we maintain our distro to ensure we pick up patches relevant to Google Cloud Platform quickly. Dataproc indeed configures the `mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version` so that the final commitJob is fast.

For something more "do-it-yourself", you can user our command-line [`bdutil` tool](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bdutil) , which also has the latest update to [use the fast FileOutputCommitter](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bdutil/blob/master/conf/hadoop2/mapred-template.xml#L142).